# Can't ssh to spot aws instance with command that was working before. Connection times out,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Three weeks ago, I could launch an aws instance spot and ssh to it using:

```
ssh -v -i /home/me/.ssh/aws3.pem ubuntu@ec2-3-145-53-84.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

where the adress was the one under 'Public IPv4 DNS'. Now they have changed the interface and when I go through the hops of launching a spot instance, and it runs, and I get the Public IPv4 DNS, and I plug it in the command above, I get:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-145-53-84.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com [3.145.53.84] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 3.145.53.84 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-3-145-53-84.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Is this really a programming question?  It seems to be about server administration.

Comment: feel free to migrate

Comment: There's no migrate path to https://serverfault.com, except for moderators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. In the new launch menu you have to replace the default
security group (under additional launch parameters - optional) by one of the existing ones (I picked launch-wizard-1). I guess they updated the default launch security group to something less user friendly.

[image]